# A typo in Spivak's solution?

Tags: calculus

> **Problem** [image]
>
> **Solution**
>
> [image]

I honestly cannot figure out what he is doing. On one hand, I think Spivak wants to write $|\phi(b)/b^n| > 1/2$ instead of $|\phi(b)/b^2| < 1/2$. On the other hand, how does he justify $b^n(1 + \frac{\phi(b)}{b^n}) > b^n/2$?

How does he know $\phi(b)/b^n \geq 0$? I guess we could assume $\phi(b) /b^n = 0$ for large $b$, but he doesn't say that at all.

Finally, I am very perplexed as to why he chooses $b > 0$. In a proof he did in the example, he chose $|x| > 1$. So I first actually thought of doing $|b| > 1, 2\phi(b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that Spivak started by setting the question for the case $n=2$, and then saw that it could easily be generalized, but failed to edit the $2$s to $n$s in a couple of places. It is so easily done, especially with the small characters in subscripts and superscripts! Otherwise the text is correct, as far as I can see. Don't forget that $\phi(b)/b^n$ may be negative; so $|\phi(b)/b^n| < 1/2$ ensures that $1/2<1+\phi(b)/b^n<3/2$ (but we don't need the upper bound). Finally, we need to generate both positive and negative values for $x^n+ \phi (x)$, so $b$ is chosen for the positive value while $a$ is chosen for the negative one.

Comment: I don't see $3/2$ anywhere in his writing.

Comment: @sizz: Yes, because it's irrelevant: the upper bound $3/2$ isn't needed. If my mentioning it is distracting, please just ignore it.

Comment: But how does he even know a $b$ have the property that the quotient is less than 1/2? This comes out of the limit I guess? SO technically he could say $| \phi(b)/b^n | < 1/n$?

Comment: @sizz: There is such a $b$ because of the condition $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\phi(x)/x^n$. This means that, given any positive number $\varepsilon$ (e.g. $\varepsilon= 1/2$), there is a number $x_\varepsilon$ such that $|\phi(x)/x^n|<\varepsilon$ whenever $x>x_\varepsilon$; just take $b$ to be any such number (e.g. $b=x_\varepsilon + 1$).

Answer (score 0):

He is correct except for the $2$ exponent. He can choose such a $b$ because $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\phi(x)/x^n=0$. The other inequality follows from the "reverse triangle inequality" $|u+v|\ge |u|-|v|$.

Comment: But $b$ must be very big no? If I choose a small $b$ he can't say anything. He is correct with $b^2$ and not $b^n$?

Comment: I had missed the $2$ issue and edited. Sorry. Yes, $b$ should be big, because $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ deals with large $x$.

Comment: Then why doesn't he say so? That is he needs to choose a large $b$? Could you also expand on the reverse triangle inequality in this problem a bit?